# System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot load type

Tags: c#, remoting

I have uploaded my application to Client .We are getting "System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot load type" error .I am new to use remoting.Can any one let me know how to resolve this issue.Same set of files are working in my local server .Its throughing System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot load type error while connecting to remote server .I have tried several ways but in vain

Error Occured while connecting RemoteServer.System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot load type  RemoteServer.SPN.ChargebackSPNRemoteServer,   RemoteServer.SPN, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationListener.Activate(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.PrivateProcessMessage(MethodBase mb, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.IActivator.Activate(IConstructionCallMessage msg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.LocalActivator.DoRemoteActivation(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.LocalActivator.Activate(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.AppDomainLevelActivator.Activate(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.ClientContextTerminatorSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage reqMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.Activate(RemotingProxy remProxy, IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.InternalActivate(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(IMessage reqMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at  RemoteServer.SPN.ChargebackSPNRemoteServer..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at Com. Service.Items.InProcess.SPNServiceProvider.ConnectDBServerRemote(String p_strURLforRemoteSite)
2014-10-03 11:00:58,251 [5084] ERROR  - InnerException RemoteServer.System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot load type  RemoteServer.SPN.ChargebackSPNRemoteServer,  . RemoteServer.SPN, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationListener.Activate(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.PrivateProcessMessage(MethodBase mb, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.IActivator.Activate(IConstructionCallMessage msg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.LocalActivator.DoRemoteActivation(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.LocalActivator.Activate(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.AppDomainLevelActivator.Activate(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.ClientContextTerminatorSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage reqMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.Activate(RemotingProxy remProxy, IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.InternalActivate(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(IMessage reqMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at  RemoteServer.SPN.ChargebackSPNRemoteServer..ctor()

Comment: We need more information. Have you tried debugging it on the client machine? Is there anything in the EventLog?

Comment: We are not getting any exception in event log files .We have deployed the same files in our server .It worked well in local environent.But not working at client location